# Prove $C_0(R^n)$ is closed in $L^\infty(R^n)$ but is not dense in it

Tags: real-analysis

For the not density:

If for $f\in L^{\infty}(R^n)$ exist a sequence$\{f_n\}\in C_0(R^n)$ so that $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^{\infty}$-norm , $f$ must necessary be continuous (for the uniform convergence).But this have to be true for $\chi_E$ with E set mesaurable.

But for the clousure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $f\in C_0(\Bbb{R}^n)$ iff $f$ is continuous and $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = 0$$

So if we take any convergent sequence of continuous functions w.r.t $L^\infty$ norm and $f_n \to f$ it follows (as you already mentioned) that $f$ is continuous as well. Moreover we have for each $f_n$ that it holds $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{x\to-\infty} f_n(x) = 0$$ because $f_n \in C_0(\Bbb{R}^n)$. But this implies $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x) = 0$$ as well what easily follows from the convergence $f_n \to f$ w.r.t to $$||\cdot||_\infty$$ because $$\lim_{x\to\infty} |f(x)| \le ||f_n - f||_\infty + \lim_{x\to\infty}|f_n(x)| \le \varepsilon$$ for $n$ large enough. So we have $f\in C_0(\Bbb{R}^n)$  hence $C_0(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is closed

Comment: My proof of density is right?

Comment: @GiuliaB. yes it is